# Count or show total number of rows until the date is met

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, selectedvalue

I have a table with Open Date and Fill Date. I need to count the total req numbers for each month until the fill date of the req.

For example, the req number 79096 has open date of 12/1/2021 and fill date of 6/10/2022, I want the req number to add to the total from January, 2021 up to June, 2022. When July, 2022 hits, that's the only time that the req number will not add up to the total.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Zzv.png)

I've tried this code so far and used it as a filter but the chart is not showing anything.

Opened Reqs = var _rangeStart=FIRSTDATE('04_calendar'[Date])
var _rangeEnd=LASTDATE('04_calendar'[Date])
return
if(AND(
SELECTEDVALUE('02_requisition_table'[OPEN_DATE])>=_rangeStart,
SELECTEDVALUE('02_requisition_table'[FILL_DATE])<_rangeEnd),
1,0)

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lyJq.png)